# Fetch the file name after clicking the download button from Save as dialog box in Cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I have a test case, where I've to click on the button to download the file. The click is triggering a native event (Chrome browser-Save as dialog box). The Save As dialog box opened by the browser contains the file name (string), the file name is generated by the server dynamically. Is there any way to grab the file-name from Save-As Dialog box generated by Chrome Browser using Cypress?

Comment: You say that when you click to trigger the save-as dialog the server generates the name, is there a request for that info? i.e. when you click, do you see network activity in the dev console? If so, you could setup a route to watch for that request and grab the info from the response. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question already that took me a while to get a good solution and Cypress still offers no support to handle this very common scenario.

Two workarounds I have found to handle this:

1. Extract from the `download` Cypress event
   If you download a file, it will show on the Cypress logs a download event, and if you click on it, this shows on the console log:
   [Download log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPQmR.png)

So, Cypress has the `Saved To` value, which includes the full path to the file. Only way I found to extract that value is this way, where consoleProps["Saved To"] contains the value you want.

```
  cy.on('log:added', ({ name, consoleProps }) => {
    if (name === 'download') {
      downloadedFile = consoleProps['Saved To'];
    }
  });
```

2. Intercept the download request
   On the response from the download, the filename may be included in the Content-Disposition header, so you can intercept the request and extract the value from there.
   In my case, res.headers['content-disposition'] equals `content-disposition: attachment; filename=Report.xls`, so just need to extract the filename from that string.

```
  cy.intercept('POST', '/download', (req) => {
    req.continue((res) => {
      console.log(res.headers['content-disposition']);
    });
  })
```